# serverless framework deploy fails on AWS

Tags: aws-cloudformation, serverless-framework, aws-serverless

> sls deploy --verbose

I encounter the problem like

```
Serverless: Split stack started…
Serverless: Uploading CloudFormation file to S3…logStack.json
Serverless: Uploading CloudFormation file to S3…apiStack.json
Serverless: Uploading CloudFormation file to S3…permissionStack.json
Serverless: Uploading CloudFormation file to S3…
Serverless: Uploading artifacts…
Serverless: Uploading service .zip file to S3 (20.81 MB)…
Serverless: Validating template…
Serverless: Uploading CloudFormation file to S3…
Serverless: Uploading artifacts…
Serverless: Uploading service .zip file to S3 (20.81 MB)…
Serverless: Validating template…

The CloudFormation template is invalid: S3 error: Unable to get the object https://s3.amazonaws.com/folderName.../compiled-cloudformation-template.json

For debugging logs, run again after setting the “SLS_DEBUG=*” environment variable.

Your Environment Information -----------------------------
OS: linux
Node Version: 8.9.4
Serverless Version: 1.27.3
```

One thing raised my attention, from the log message before the error message, the compiled-cloudformation-template.json should be in the URL start with s3.us-west-2.amazonaws rather than s3.amazonaws

Is this the issue that leads to the s3 error. If so, how could I fix it? If not, what is the real problem (this is not the first time I deployed, and I have several successful experiences before).

Appreciate to help of any kinds.

Comment: Could you please share more about your serverless.yml file? The configuration should handle the S3 upload and created the functions from there. Have you defined your provider.region?

Comment: @Cleriston Thanks, and I have fixed this issue. It is because of some restriction of my AWS account. After I got the admin authority, this problem gets solved. It is a bit of strange, but that is it...